# An unknown AWS EC2 instance running which recreates even after termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running amazon AWS ECS container which creates one single instance of EC2. I made sure that it is 1 instance when I created ECS.

My issue is that I have another instance running in EC2 and amazon has sent me an email that I am using double of the free quota and will be charged.

But I am not sure why this second EC2 instance is coming from.

I have terminated it many times but it is recreated. When I terminate it, this is the prompt i receive which advises me that it is created from EBS but there is no app in EBS

```
On an EBS-backed instance, the default action is for the root EBS volume to be deleted when the instance is terminated. 
Storage on any local drives will be lost.
```

This name of the instance is.
**ECS Instance - amazon-ecs-cli-setup-ecs-cricketscorer**

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check if you have any `Auto Scaling Groups` that you do not recognize. It is most probably being created because of it. If not, change your account password and deactivate/delete your existing AccessKeys.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was auto scaling group causing issues. Just deleted.